# Use of Arrow Keys

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What I want is something like this

By pressing the <kbd>Arrow Key down</kbd>, for example, `button1` do the action of a click

`ArrowKeyDown = button1.Click` and by doing that click my image move all through my `picturebox`. and the same for going up, `right` and`left`.

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms application, or a web application?

Comment: can u be a little more descriptive?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - seems like WinForm!

Comment: @Rodrigo - show us why you tried~

Comment: You can disassociate the command (arrow button, mouse click) from the action - [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

Comment: @AppDeveloper: "seems like", but we shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: Devendra is right. Whatever action you are trying to do, make it into a function.  Then you create the mouse click action and a ArrowKeyDown action call the same function.

Comment: it is a Windows Form Application. 
By pressing the arrow key right i what that the ation that happpen by making click on a button also happend by pressing the key. i tried Keys.Right = button01.Click;

Comment: i call other functions with that button.Click that function is that the cordinate x increase x += pasox; that makes my image moves right. The image moves on a pictureBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use the [`Form.KeyPreview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) but before you can use this you must set the Property of the Form `KeyPreview = true` and you mentioned the `Button Click` you can achieve this by using the [`.PerformClick Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx)

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
        button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
                button1.PerformClick();
                break;
            case Keys.Right:
                button1.PerformClick();
                break;
            case Keys.Down:
                button1.PerformClick();
                break;
            case Keys.Up:
                button1.PerformClick();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Okay");
    }
```

Comment: i tried that but i dont know why when i press the key nothing happend.
Sorry ive just started using this program in january. My program already does what it has to does but i want to add more things like that. instead of using buttons use the keyboard.

Comment: did you actually write the event for `buttonClick`?

Comment: i did. I thought that my code was wrong and i change the instruction for something easy but i got the same result. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Take all the code from you button1.Click and put it in a separate function.

Then you can call the function from your button1.Click and your key Down event.

Inside the key down you will have to use an if statement and the e.KeyCode to make sure you have the right key before calling your subroutine.

If your code looks like this

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //do something here
 }
```

It will now be more like this

```
private void doSomething()
{
    //do something here
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    doSomething();
}

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
    {
        doSomething();
    }
    else if(e.keyCode==Keys.Right)
    {
         doSomethingElse();
    }
     //etc.etc
}
```

Another more clean approach for the key down event is to use a switch statement

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Down:
            doSomething();
            break;
        case Keys.Right:
            //do Something Else
            break;
        case Keys.Up:
            //do Something Else
            break;
        case Keys.Left:
            //do Something Else
            break;
        default:
            //they hit a key you did not handle
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question, can you try to clarify?